# How to handle rebasing after base branch has been merged?

Tags: git

I was developing a feature branch (A) based off another feature branch (B), and now the branch I was developing off of (B) has been merged to master.

Git now sees A as being in conflict with master because I have the changes from B, but so does master because B was merged. I am therefore unable to merge A. Merging master *into* A makes no difference.

How can this situation be resolved? Rebasing onto master leads to a lot of manual conflict resolution. My branch (A) does not change any files that are changed in master; all the conflicts result from A including B's changes, which are already in master.

Answer (score 3):

Usually what you want to do in this case is to use `git rebase --onto`.  This lets you specify both the original base branch and the new one.  So you'd do something like this:

```
$ git checkout A
$ git rebase --onto master B
```

This treats the original base branch as B and places the commits on top of that on master instead.  Usually Git will detect this case automatically and a normal rebase will work, although it will fail in some cases, notably if you do a squash merge.

Comment: Unfortunately this leads to conflicts in files neither of us touched. I believe you that this is intended for this situation, but unfortunately in my case something is going wrong with it.

Comment: Does it work if you manually specify the hash of the commit just underneath A (that is, the last commit from B in branch A) instead of B in the rebase command?

Comment: In the interests of time, I made a new branch, manually copied my changes over file by file, and deleted the old branch. So I can't say. I would have loved to understand the behavior but in this case time constraints took precedence.

Answer (score 2):

Another option, if you are confident that all of the conflicts are due to A including B's changes, is a merge using the recursive strategy with ours option:

From the docs:

> This option forces conflicting hunks to be auto-resolved cleanly by favoring our version. Changes from
>                  the other tree that do not conflict with our side are reflected to the merge result. For a binary file,
>                  the entire contents are taken from our side.